# How can I test if a particular alias is defined?

Tags: bash, alias

I have a bash script that needs to behave differently if a particular alias is defined. Is there a way to test if a particular command is an alias in bash?

Comment: `type -t <command>`

Comment: @jimmij: You should make that into an answer.

Answer (score 29):

If `alias` is passed an alias name without `=value`, it just prints the alias definition if that alias is defined, or fails with an error if there's no such alias.

So you can just do:

```
if alias your_alias_name >/dev/null 2>&1; then 
  do_something
else 
  do_another_thing; 
fi
```

(replace `your_alias_name` as required)

Answer (score 13):

I’m gonna make [@jimmij’s comment from 5 years ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288512/how-can-i-test-if-a-particular-alias-is-defined#comment504459_288512) into an answer:

`type -t` is designed for exactly that purpose. It will output `alias` if the given command is an alias. If the command does not exist, it won’t output anything, which means you don’t need to redirect its stderr or something.

Example:

```bsh
if [ "$(type -t foo)" = 'alias' ]; then
    echo 'foo is an alias'
else
    echo 'foo is not an alias'
fi
```

Note that the `-t` switch is not defined in POSIX. Shells other than bash might not implement it.

Answer (score 0):

**Word of warning**:

> Shell functions and aliases are limited to the shell and do not work
> in executed shell scripts.

Found in https://askubuntu.com/a/98796 , confirmed by my own bitter experience.

Somewhat annoyingly this is not mentioned explicitly in the [relevant section of the Bash user manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Interactive-Shells), the only hint is that

> Alias expansion (see Aliases) is performed by default.

which was not intuitive enough for me; YMMV.

In short, all the technologies mentioned in the other answers *work only if you check aliases defined in the same script* (or in another file you `source`-d into your script). You cannot check from within a (non-interactive) script whether an alias was defined in the shell where you invoked said script.

Here is a little script `aliastest.sh` that demonstrates the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

is_alias() {
    if [[ "$(type -t $1)" == "alias" ]]; then
        echo "$1 is an alias"
    else
        echo "Cannot find $1"
    fi
}

# == MAIN ==

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <command> [ <command> ...]"
    exit 1
fi

for cmd in $@; do
    is_alias $cmd
done
```

Let's assume you defined the popular `ll` alias in your shell with the command `alias ll='ls -alF'` (you may have it already). If you run `./aliastest.sh ll` it will tell you `Cannot find ll`.

But despair not, **there is a workaround**:

If you tell Bash to run your script as "interactive", then it'll "see" the aliases defined in the shell you invoked it from:

```
bash -i aliastest.sh ll
```

It will answer `ll is an alias`.

Answer (score -2):

You can write like this

```bash
[[ $(type your_alias) == *"alias" ]] && echo "alias defined" || echo "alias undefined"
```

Example:

```bash
[[ $(type fd) == *"alias" ]] && echo "fd is an alias" || echo "fd is not an alias"
```

Another option can be

```bash
[[ -z $(alias | grep 'll=') ]] && echo "alias not found" || echo "alias found"
```

Comment: Deb 11, not working as presented. `ll` is alias to `ls -l`, but `[[ $(type ll) == *"alias" ]] && echo "alias defined" || echo "alias undefined"` results `alias undefined`. If is isn't the way your suggested answer should be understood, you should [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/740904/edit) it so that how this is supposed to be done is clear.

Comment: This does not work in `bash` as the `type` command never outputs anything that starts with the string `alias`.

Comment: Your modified answer would say that `ll` was an alias if the string `ll=` occurs in any alias definition, regardless of whether `ll` was an alias or not. (A solution for `zsh` would look identical to a solution for `bash`, BTW).